# Uniformly convergent for functions problem

Tags: uniform-convergence

The problem is as follows.

Let {$f_n$} is defined on $[0,1]$ and suppose that $lim_{n-> infinity}$ $f_n(x_n)=0$ for convergent sequence in $[0,1]$,  {$x_n$}.

Show that {$f_n$} is converges uniformly to $f=0$ on $[0,1]$.

I think using the bolzano-weierstrass theorem but i get stuck here. I'd like to show that
Every sequence {$x_n$} in $[0,1]$, $lim_{n->infinity} |f_n(x_n)|=0$ .
Please give me full explanation.

Comment: Prove by contradiction. Use the fact that any sequence in $[0,1]$ has  convergent subsequence.

Comment: Give me full explanation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f_n$ does not converges to $0$ uniformly the there exist $\epsilon >0$, integers $n_1<n_2...$ and point $x_k$ such that $|f_{n_k}(x_k)| >\epsilon$ for all $k$. There is a subsequence, say $y_k$, of $(x_k)$ which converges to some point $x$. But then the hypothesis is violated since $f_n(y_n)$ does not tend to $0$.

Comment: 1. The second line, what is 'for all x'?   And                            2. ${f_n{_k}}$ is subsequence of $f_n$ ?                                  3. $y_k$ is just convergent subsequence of $x_k$. Then why it satisfies |$f(y_k)$| doesn't approach to 0?

Comment: @Crawl 1. There was a typo. 2. Yes. 3. The inequality $|f_{n_k}(x_k)| >\epsilon$ holds for any subsequence also.